# How do I get set the font I need in CS6 and lose Myriad forever?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

How do I set a font so that stupid Myriad does not appear each time I open a new image? I have to plow through a hundred other fonts to get back to the one I need every single time I open a new image.

I resent that Adobe thinks they know what I need and wastes my time slogging through each and every time I need the font I need ... and Adobe sets Myriad as the default.

I am beginning to despise the company for several things they are doing of late.

How do I set the font I need and make it stay put for each successive image that I open?  I have close to 80 more images to do.

Answer (score 2):

Like several Adobe applications.... change the font **with no document open**.

This will cause your new font selection to be the default for **new** documents. It will *not* alter any already existing documents.

---

If you want to "despise" Adobe, do it for the right reasons.... their silly subscription pricing model that is costing you WAY more and giving you really NOTHING in return.

Comment: Hmm... Im not sure the second part is really correct. The subscription model is considerably cheaper then the old model. Even on  a multi year perspective. HOWEVER, i do agree that your paying for air though as their quality control has severely gone down.

Comment: Back in the old days you paid for every release cycle. It was predictable and one could stop at the current version (for example when the company model shifted into less graphics heavy work). Now you not only need to pay annually - the release cycle got wider, giving you less in return. Now you don't "own" the product - you basically rent it. This means that the basic tools of your team stop working once the subscription is no longer paid, leaving all existing documents inaccessible. It's a hostage situation.

Comment: Plus of course, Adobe is not obligated to do business with _your_ company. Since they have the ability to just cease doing business with you they essentially have a remote control to destroy your graphics department at will.

Comment: @Joojaa the subscription is NOT cheaper. It's only cheaper for *casual users* who don't necessarily need the tools every day. It's like renting a car or owning a car. Owning is FAR CHEAPER if you intend to drive every day. Renting is cheaper if you only need a car 1 month out of the year.

Comment: @Scott well a licence of the suite cost thousands of dollars you can get 61$ So lets say the suite cost 1200$ that would mean that it takes about 19 months to reach the same price. In reality its longer than that. But going forward I still think that this is not good for archival purposes. What im more concerned about is that there is no feedback for lemon releases. In previous times i could say no to a upgrade and vote with my money. Now i really can not (Except i have voted i am frozen to CS 5.5 for my personal projects)

Comment: @Joojaa  previously $1200 to upgrade the entire suite... releases were about every 18 months.. but I could choose to upgrade every 24, 36, 48 months. Or just skip a version. The upgrade was on MY schedule. Now. $600 every 12 months no exception. Even if I don't upgrade the apps, i still have to pay the $600 annually. So Adobe has locked in users to spending at least 50% more annually. In addition, if I don't pay.. I can't open my COPYRIGHTED ARTWORK. So Adobe is holding my own files hostage unless I pay them.

Comment: We've digressed a bit too much probably. But It should be illegal what Adobe has done. To me is seems like a CLEAR CUT anti-trust case. I'm ashamed of the industry as a whole.. AIGA, the Graphic Artists Guild... any industry organization that failed to fight this with all they had. They've all rolled over and let Adobe hinder the industry for profits. At the *bare minimum** there should be an **exit strategy** for the subscription. I choose not to renew.. I can buy a perpetual license for the current version and I'm locked out of any subscription pricing for at least 2 years or something.

Comment: Software subscriptions are just **horrible** for any user. It doesn't matter what software.... subscriptions favor the vendor, never the buyer. Microsoft is equally taking advantage of their customers with the whole 365 thing.

Comment: .. and this is why I still work in CS6 99% of the time even though I have a CC2018 subscription. I want to be able to access my files 5 years from now without paying Adobe to do so.

Comment: @Scott agreed it should be seen as anti competetive. Perhaps we should start pooling money in a fund to make a new software?

Comment: @Scott, I'm from Denmark and I wrote to the Danish Competition and Consumer Authority about Adobe's subscription model, which I also find very unfair. After a month they actually called me and said that it was an interesting subject, but that they really don't have the power to go up against big companies like Adobe. So my government is weaker than my graphics applications company. Maybe it's a case for the European Commissioner for Competition (who is from Denmark). She has an ongoing campaign against the large corporations.

Comment: @joojaa, I would love that! But I'm unsure if its naive.

Comment: Too bad Wolff. I think it's along the same lines as Microsoft embedding Internet Explorer in Windows... the US government stepped in there. Adobe has had a monopoly on some industries for 20-30 years, especially since buying Macromedia. I am dumbfounded as to why their price fixing/gouging is not an ant-trust situation.